# How can I align the background of a text vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have a  tag and a background added to it. How can I align its background with it vertically?

```css
h1 {
  top: 90px;
  left: 90px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>TEXT</h1>
```

Comment: top + left but no position ? can you rephrase your question ? background of a text ? do you mean clip-text or something else ?